# How does the drying of dishes outdoors by a cool wind on an overcast day relate to heat?

Tags: thermodynamics, friction, evaporation

On a hot summer day, dishes dry outdoors almost immediately. At other times, a cool wind with an overcast sky will sometimes also dry dishes outdoors after a while. I am aware that some heat still gets through the clouds on overcast days, but I'm guessing a significant factor on such occasions would be the speed of a cool wind. My notion is that friction is at play somehow when the wind meets the dishes. But how does the friction of a cool wind relate to heat, which I assume must be present for water to evaporate?

Comment: Try your best to only use friction when you know that the force law of friction applies. Friction, viscosity, quadratic air resistance, and similar other things, are all different, and should not be mixed. Your problem is actually much more to do with dry air being blown over the dishes. In particular, the air that absorbed some moisture from the dishes is being blown away, and that is the main part of the drying up.

Comment: Some topics to read up on: Distribution of molecule kinetic energy, vapor pressure, cooling due to evaporation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the water needs heat to evaporate, and the air, despite being well below $100\text{ C}$, is happy to give it to the water. Not in the form of friction, but just heat flowing from the air to the water the way heat flows from your electric stove to your pan when you put your pan on the stove.

In a container with water and air, water will evaporate until the fraction of water (or the partial pressure - the amount of air pressure that is due to water) in the air is the "saturated vapor pressure" given in this plot. This is also called "100% humidity" in everyday language. [Credit for the plot](https://www.chemguide.co.uk/physical/phaseeqia/vapourpress.html)

[image]

The reason this happens at all is that when liquid water turns into gaseous water, entropy increases. Water stops evaporating when the change in *free energy* ($\Delta E-T\Delta S$) for evaporating more water is no longer negative. When there's no water in the air, $\Delta E$ is positive, but $-T\Delta S$ is negative because $\Delta S$ is positive. Not sure what level you're at, but if none of that makes sense - suffice to say you need to learn thermodynamics before this can be properly understood. At 100C and 100kPa pressure, all the water would prefer to be in the gaseous state, but below that temperature, still some fraction would prefer to be in the gaseous state.

In a non-windy environment, the water evaporates until the air near the thing drying is saturated, then it stops until that water diffuses away from the thing and leaves space for more water. In a windy environment, fresh unsaturated air is continuously being delivered to the thing you want to dry. On average, the air around the water is dryer than if the air was stationary, so the water evaporates more quickly.

Comment: Thanks very much for the illuminating and thorough answer and comments.